# Bluetooth on my Raspberry Pi 2B does not work

Tags: bluetooth

My Pi is 2B Rev1.1

- I connected HC-08 Bluetooth module on pin8,10.
- I use Raspberry Pi OS.
- In `/boot/configuration.txt`

  ```
  enable_uart=1
  ```
- In `/boot/cmdline.txt`

  ```
  console=tty1 root=PATUUID=e77fdc5c-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes root wait quiet splash Plymouth.ignore-serial-serialconsoles
  ```
- I upgraded the Pi with the command
  `sudo apt update &&sudo apt upgrade`
- I installed bluez with the command
  `sudo apt install bluetooth pi-bluetooth bluez blueman`
- I checked bluetooth status with the command
  `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service`. It shows `Active:Inactive(dead)`.
- Then I try to use `sudo modprobe btusb` to get the service up. It shows `Active:active(running)`
- I use command `bluetoothctl`. There is no device found.
- After further research. I found the following command `sudo systemctl status hciuart.service`. It shows `Active:active(dead)`.
- And `raspberrypi systemd[1]:condition` check resulted in configure `Bluetooth Modems connected by UART being skipped`
- After further research, I tried to use the command `sudo systemctl hciattach /dev/serial0 bcm43xx 115200`.
  It shows `bcm43xx_init Initialization timeout`
- I tried different parameters and still failed to get this done successfully.

So far I am focusing on the error message from `hciuart.service`. I am trying to figure out what caused the skip.

I am new to the kernel thing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "btusb" would enable a bluetooth USB device, no? "pins 8 and 10" are not a USB device - can you specify exactly what you connected to each pin - I suspect you connected RX to RX and TX to TX - a common rookie mistake

Comment: An `HC-08` module will not be recognised by the RPi as a Bluetooth device and doesn't use the Bluetooth software stack used by the on-board Bluetooth on later RPi models. The `HC-0*` Bluetooth UART Communication Modules work as bridges between the serial communication on the pins of the RPi to Bluetooth over the air. You need a serial library to read/write to the HC-08 device. For example PySerial in Python.

Comment: @Jaromanda X I was confused about the command to bring bluetooth up too. But btusb worked. Pin8(GPIO14,UART0_TXD)<->RXD on HC-08 module,Pin10(GPIO15,UART0_RXD)<-> TXD on HC-08 module.

Comment: @ukBaz I do not know this. This sounds make sense to me. That maybe the reason it is skipped.I will study Pyserial first. I have another question if this is true, if i use my smart phone to pair with HC-08 module it should work and can pair successfully,right?

Comment: HC-08 is a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device and can be in one of two modes: Peripheral (which advertises and other devices can connect to it) or Central (which scans for and connects to peripherals). Which mode it is in can be changed with AT commands. More information about that here: https://www.instructables.com/HC-08-Bluetooth-UART-Communication-Module-V24-User/. In peripheral mode you can connect to it from your phone. Use a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to test.

Comment: @Daniel - Sorry, I should have also said that if you have a follow up question then please post a *new question* and (maybe) link back (using the URL) to the previous question (if relevant). Asking further questions in the comments section tends to break the Q&A mechanism of Stack Exchange, and that is not what the comemnts are for. Comments are meant for users to ask the original poster for clarifications only, clarification which should then be editted into the question post. Plus comments can not be voted on. And comments get deleted over time. Thanks.

Comment: @ukBaz - Please use the answer section for answers, and not the comment section.

Comment: @greenonline I don't believe this meets the standard to be an answer. I am just trying to steer this in the right direction

Comment: @greenonline Sorry. I really need to read through the comment format.

Comment: @ukbaz your direction really is the right one. I followed your comments. Now I can first communicate between mincom(9600baud) on my pi through bluetooth and app(lightblue) on my cellphone. I do not have time to study  nRF connect(it can receive,but do not know how to send). Finally I can write a sample python code to receive data from my cellphone. THANKS so much for your help.

Comment: @Greenonline please let me know how should I do to keep this question more useful for others who have same issue.